# Copy Paint object

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint

Okay, I am not sure how to describe this. I have made a Class called ScreenAreas that defines specific areas on the screen. Later on, I am drawing these ScreenAreas.

What I would like to do, is to couple Paint attributes (Color, strokeWidth, Shaddowsettings, etc) to these ScreenAreas, in such a way, that I don't have to reset all these attributes, when drawing them again.

This is my ScreenArea Class:
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;

```
public class ScreenArea {

private int xMin;
private int yMin;
private int xMax;
private int yMax;
private Paint paint;

public ScreenArea(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, Paint paint) {
    this.setXMin(x1);
    this.setXMax(x2);
    this.setYMin(y1);
    this.setYMax(y2);
    this.paint = paint;

}

// I removed the getters and setters for clarity

public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawRect(this.xMin, this.yMin, this.xMax, this.yMax, this.paint);
}
}
```

And in my main Class I am constructing them using:

```
paint.setColor(Color.rgb(10,10,10));
area1 = new ScreenArea (
            0,
            0,
            100,
            100,
            paint);

paint.setColor(Color.rgb(100,100,100));
area2 = new ScreenArea(
            20, 
            20, 
            80, 
            80,
            paint);
```

When I try to draw them, I simply do:

```
area1.draw(canvas);
area2.draw(canvas);
```

Both of the area's will be given the same color, though. In fact they are given the last color used. Probably, this is because the Paint objects in the ScreenArea are simply pointing to the same Paint object in the main Class. The question is, how to solve this problem!

Anyone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should remember that [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object has a [copy constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#Paint(android.graphics.Paint)). So instead of:

```
this.paint = paint;
```

within your `ScreenArea` constructor, you can use:

```
this.paint = new Paint(paint);
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is good, but if for some reason you don't want to instantiate a new `Paint` (perhaps because you're inside `onDraw()`, which I realize is not the case here) then you can use [Paint.set()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#set%28android.graphics.Paint%29).

> public void set (Paint src) Added in API level 1
>
> Copy the fields from src into this paint. This is equivalent to
>   calling get() on all of the src fields, and calling the corresponding
>   set() methods on this.

Replace `private Paint paint;` with `private Paint paint = new Paint();` and then `this.paint = paint;` (which just copies to pointer to the `Paint` object) with `this.paint.set(paint);` (which copies the fields from `paint` to `this.paint`.

Comment: Just from the Paint class's documentation the idea to use Paint.set seems like a very good idea. In my testing, though, I encountered the problem that, when modifying the source Paint object, the copy could also get modified. This was the case e.g. for set ColorFilters. Therefore I am not sure whether internally the set-method works like the documentation tells us.